# How to make Button in background tappable with ScrollView on top?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `ScrollView` that slides over the header, but I need a button in the header tappable.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I need the "Start" button tappable, but because the `ScrollView` is on top, it's not tappable. I tried playing with the `zIndex` but the scroll no longer occurred on top of the header.

This is the sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                Button("Start") {
                    isPresented = true
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(16)
            }
            .padding(80)
            .background(Color(.label).ignoresSafeArea())
            .assign(heightTo: $headerHeight)
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: headerHeight)
                VStack {
                    ForEach((0...50), id: \.self) {
                        Text("Some text \($0)")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color(.white))
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("Button tapped"))
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    /// Binds the height of the view to a property.
    func assign(heightTo height: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color.clear.onAppear {
                    height.wrappedValue = geometry.size.height
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved while making the scroll view slide over the header?

Comment: Why not list with section? It’s doesn’t seems optimal  way of button tapping, the way you want.

Comment: The visual effect is not the same, I need to show the sliding over the header.. almost like a bottom sheet sliding over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Version 2.0.0

---

I decided to updated my answer and because it can be confused if i put them in same answer, I am putting it here, to keep codes and answers much clear and easy to read. about new update, it is basically the same way but a souped-up version!

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { screenGeometry in
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                        
                        Color.clear                         // Test if we are in Center! >> change Color.clear to Color.blue and uncomment down code for Capsule() to see it!
                            .frame(height: headerHeight)
                            //.overlay(Capsule().frame(height: 2.0))
                            .overlay( HeaderView(isPresented: $isPresented)
                                        .background( GeometryReader { proxy in Color.clear.onAppear { headerHeight = proxy.size.height } } )
                                        .offset(y: headerHeight + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.top - offsetY))
                        
                        ZStack {
                            
                            Color.white.cornerRadius(20.0)
                            
                            VStack { ForEach((0...30), id: \.self) { item in Text("item " + item.description); Divider().padding(.horizontal) } }.padding(.top)
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .overlay( GeometryReader { proxy in Color.clear.onChange(of: proxy.frame(in: .global).minY) { newValue in offsetY = newValue } } )
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .position(x: screenGeometry.size.width/2, y: screenGeometry.size.height/2)
            .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) { Alert(title: Text("Button tapped")) }
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
            
        }
        .shadow(radius: 10.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.clear
            
            VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                
                button(color: Color(UIColor.systemTeal))
                
                Text("Some text 1").bold()
                
                Text("Some text 2").bold()
                
                button(color: Color(UIColor.green))
                
                Text("Some text 3").bold()
                
                Text("Some text 4").bold()
                
                button(color: Color.purple)
                
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
    func button(color: Color) -> some View {
        
        return Button(action: { isPresented.toggle() }, label: {
            
            Text("Start")
                .bold()
                .padding()
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(color)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(16)
            
        })
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the hardcoded 16px is still there in the offset, which doesn't work well when reused in various screens. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: You want no padding on ZStack? you mean no padding on item List View?

Comment: In the offset, you have `.offset(y: headerHeight + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.top + 16.0 - offsetY))`. You explained this was because some autospy you saw by Apple. But when I change the padding elsewhere I have to change this number.

Comment: I can make this happen ```.offset(y: headerHeight + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.top + 8.0 - offsetY))``` but we should at least 8.0 stays! Is that you want?

Comment: but why any number? what if Apple changes something or the use of this has different padding. it sounds like it's not possible but just wondering

Comment: because im wondering if this number would even change on different devices like iPad or Mac for example

Comment: As long as you lunched your app to app Store that would not effect, your app would compiled with the version you programmed, and it would be stay same if apple change every thing from foundation even! If that is your worry, do not worry. So do you want just with 8?

Comment: No 16 is fine, it wasn't the number itself because integrating into the app will have other layouts for the header and sheet so this number will change in different use cases

Comment: As long as you gave your working version to app store your app would be layouts the same, even apple update iOS to Version 20 or 30, your app would be look like the same, but the deference is here, if you want compile your current Version with Xcode Version 22, maybe we see some difference, and that is understandable, because our code is old, and we are using updated Xcode!

Comment: I could be able to solve that **8.0 or 16.0** issue as well about ScrollView! Now We do **not** need use hard coded **8.0** any more! :)

Comment: @swiftPunk can I upgrade your solution somehow if I want to scroll only to, let's say the first button, but then the scroll goes under/behind button?

Comment: @virusss8: you can post your answer as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Version 1.0.0

---

It was not an easy Job! But I make it working with down way:

The way that I used was watching ScrollView move and using that data for app of course with power of **Almighty** GeometryReader!

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isPresented: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()

    var body: some View {
 
        GeometryReader { screenGeometry in

            ZStack {
                
                Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()

                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
  
                    VStack(spacing: 0.0) {

                        Color.clear                         // Test if we are in Center! >> change Color.clear to Color.blue and uncomment down code for Capsule() to see it!
                            .frame(height: headerHeight)
                            //.overlay(Capsule().frame(height: 2.0))
                            .overlay( ButtonView(isPresented: $isPresented)
                                        .background( GeometryReader { proxy in Color.clear.onAppear { headerHeight = proxy.size.height } } )
                                        .offset(y: headerHeight + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.top - offsetY))

                        ZStack {

                            Color.white.cornerRadius(20.0)

                            VStack { ForEach((0...30), id: \.self) { item in Text("item " + item.description); Divider().padding(.horizontal) } }.padding(.top)
   
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .overlay( GeometryReader { proxy in Color.clear.onChange(of: proxy.frame(in: .global).minY) { newValue in offsetY = newValue } } )
 
                    }

                }

            }
            .position(x: screenGeometry.size.width/2, y: screenGeometry.size.height/2)
            .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) { Alert(title: Text("Button tapped")) }
            .statusBar(hidden: true)

        }
        .shadow(radius: 10.0)

    }

}
```

---

```
struct ButtonView: View {

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: { isPresented.toggle() }, label: {
            
            Text("Start")
                .bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(16)
            
        })
        .padding(80)
  
    }
 
}
```

Comment: This is awesome thx! Question about what is the 8.0 where adding to the safe area inset? I tried removing it and is indeed needed, but what is that accounting for?

Comment: We can not do anything about it, I done autopsy on ScrollView for removing it, but it is from ScrollView itself(from Apple) we should have 8.0 in our code to being in Center! you can remove that 8 but it would off center, I do not recommend

Comment: @TruMan1: I add extra explaining in the code as well.

Comment: This is really good thanks! A posted another variation that was completely inspired by your answer. I just improved some areas, but doesn't handle orientation changes well like yours. The padding causes changes in the calculation so I was able to get rid of that since there will be various areas this will be used and can't predict the padding. Also I'm scoping the GeometryReader instead of wrapping the entire ScrollView with it (just my personal preference, not right or wrong). Last thing is I decoupled the headerHeight & offset by calculating the offset without needing to know the height.

Comment: I can see what you are trying reach, I add another update which answer that need as well. soon!

Comment: I could be able to solve that **8.0** issue as well about ScrollView! Now We do not need use hard coded **8.0** any more! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @swiftPunk's answer, I used a slightly different approach by locking the header offset to the initial diff off the scroll position:

```
struct ContentView3: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    // For sticky header
    @State private var scrollOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var headerOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var headerOffsetDiff: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: headerHeight)
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        Text("Some text 1")
                        Text("Some text 1")
                        Text("Some text 1")
                        Text("Some text 1")
                        Text("Some text 1")
                        Button(action: { isPresented.toggle() }) {
                            Text("Start")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(16)

                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear {
                                    headerHeight = geometry.size.height
                                    headerOffsetY = geometry.frame(in: .global).minY
                                }
                        }
                    )
                    .onChange(of: scrollOffsetY) { offset in
                        guard headerOffsetDiff == 0 else { return }
                        headerOffsetDiff = offset - headerOffsetY
                    }
                    .offset(y: headerOffsetY + headerOffsetDiff - scrollOffsetY)
                )
            VStack {
                ForEach((0...30), id: \.self) {
                    Text("Some text \($0)").padding(.bottom)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color(.systemBackground)
                        .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY) {
                            scrollOffsetY = $0
                        }
                }
            )
        }
        .background(
            Color(.label)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("Button tapped"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work well with orientation changes, needs to figure a good time to reset `headerOffsetDiff` to a proper value.

Comment: If any part of my answer does not feet your need, tel my plz, I will update it for you, no problem at all, just show me issue about my code, and I will fix it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing help! I learned a lot from your answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the approach below which I find super clean and does exactly what's needed. (iOS 14+ though)

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
        Section {
            ScrollableContentView()
                .zIndex(0)
        } header: {
            HeaderViewToHideUnderneath()
                .zIndex(-1)
        }
    }
}
```