# SwiftUI ScrollView allowsHitTesting for only some cells

Tags: swift, swiftui

## How can I tell a ScrollView that some of it's cells are transparent, and to ignore cell taps?

### What I'm trying to create

I'm trying to create a ScrollView that has a transparent (non-tappable) top. Similar to the Apple Maps bottom sheet.

[image]

Here's a simplified demo

[image: simple demo]

From this code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top)) {
            
            // Stationary background
            Text("Stationary Background Button")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Background button tap")
                }
            
            // Scroll content
            ScrollView {
                    
                LazyVStack {
                    
                    // Transparent (cant tap) space above scrollview
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 380)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    
                    // Tappable cell
                    Text("Scrollable cell 1")
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 600)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("scroll cell tapped")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

## What I've Tried

- Commenting out the `ScrollView` (the taps work great, but it doesn't scroll anymore).
- Adding `allowsHitTesting(true/false)` in every combination you can think of.
- Adding a geometry reader alongside the `LazyVStack` that gets current scroll offset. Then storing that in a `PreferenceKey` and using it in a `contentShape` modifier on the `ScrollView`. (This causes SUPER glitchy scrolling).

```
ZStack {
                    
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.clear
            .preference(
                key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                value: proxy.frame(in: .global).midY
            )
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { newSize in
        self.offset = newSize
    }
    ... LazyVStack goes here ...
}


// Attached to the ScrollView
.contentShape(
    OffsetShape(
        shape: Rectangle().size(
            width: 300,
            height: 270
        ),
        offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: offset)
    )
)
```

Comment: I believe the Apple Maps feature that you're referencing has a bottom view with a DragGesture and after the view is dragged to the top state, the ScrollView is enabled. I don't think it's a ScrollView with a transparent top.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same problem. The first Item in scrollView needs to pass click through.

Comment: @virusss8 This approach is a dead end. No way to make cells ignore taps. I originally asked this question because I wanted the appear/disappear gesture to happen when the `ScrollView` got to the top. I basically abandoned this approach and found it's a lot better to have a view gesture controlling appear/disappear separate from the ScrollView's motion.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892202/how-to-make-button-in-background-tappable-with-scrollview-on-top/66933741#66933741
TLDR; try to move your background view within the scroll view top spacer overlay.