# Jumpy performance issue when offset and opacity used

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a header that is fixed in place using an offset relative to the scroll position. Strangely enough though, when the contents of the scroll view has a dynamic opacity to the buttons, the offset is very jumpy:

[image]

This is the scroll view code, the `HeaderView` is "fixed" in place by pinning the offset to the scroll view's offset. The opacity seems to be causing the performance issue is on the `MyButtonStyle` style on the last line of code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 200

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { screenGeometry in
            ZStack {
                Color(.label)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                        Color.clear
                            .frame(height: headerHeight)
                            .overlay(
                                HeaderView(isPresented: $isPresented)
                                    .offset(y: offsetY != 0 ? headerHeight + screenGeometry.safeAreaInsets.top - offsetY : 0)
                            )
                        VStack(spacing: 16) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                                    Button("Button \(index)") {}
                                        .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(icon: Image(systemName: "alarm")))
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: screenGeometry.size.height)
                        .padding()
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Color.white
                                    .cornerRadius(32)
                                    .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY) { newValue in
                                        offsetY = newValue
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) { Alert(title: Text("Button tapped")) }
        }
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "bell")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
            Button(action: { isPresented = false }) {
                Text("Press")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let icon: Image

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Content(
            configuration: configuration,
            icon: icon
        )
    }

    struct Content: View {
        let configuration: Configuration
        let icon: Image

        var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing: 18) {
                Label(
                    title: { configuration.label },
                    icon: { icon.padding(.trailing, 8) }
                )
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .accessibilityHidden(true)
            }
            .padding(18)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1) // <-- Comment this out and jumpiness goes away!!
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a performance improvement that can be done to use the opacity on the button press and make the jumpiness go away? Or a different way to approach this sticky offset because not sure if this is actually the source of the issue and I use opacity in a lot of places in my app (not just button presses)? The purpose of doing it this way is so the button can be tapped instead of putting it in the background of the scroll view. Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: First, it doesn't repro for me. Second, there's a warning `"onChange(of: CGFloat) action tried to update multiple times per frame."` - it might make sense to look into it. And third, I'd suggest possibly re-evaluating how you're implementing this behavior. You're calling `onChange` many many times, and each time you're attempting to change a state variable, which causes the view to re-render. Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, or if there's another way, but this definitely feels wonky

Comment: For more context, I'm trying to give the effect of the scroll view sliding over the header. But the header can have interactions so it needs to be in the scroll view, not ZStacked behind it. It was derived from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66892202

Comment: @TruMan1: This issue is not in your part(It is Apple), it is competition between Button and ScrollView on drag Gesture! and cause that Jumpy effect! if you replace all Buttons with Texts which has no dragGesture build in, there would be no issue! then you have 2 ways! make your Button out of Text or build a custom ScrollView which is open source for you to control on drag.

Comment: @NewDev ya I'm about to give up and accept SwiftUI can't handle this. In UIKit I'd simply pin it to the global view. I'm examining a completely different approach but running into limitations there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67039947 :(

Comment: @swiftPunk those are 2 really rough options. I can't avoid basic button functionality and I certainly don't want to recreate the native ScrollView, I'm banging my head against the wall for weeks on this one

Comment: @TruMan1: the Button or ScrollView that shipped with Xcode are just for Hello World project! For real work we should do custom code. You think the Button that you are using is alright? No, it has lots of issue with it, in drag in scroll, in long press, double tap! the Gestures is not working right with apple button. same  thing with Toggle, with TabView, all has issue or THE NavigationView, should I tell more? You tell me one thing working fine in Xcode? just one thing without issue! LoL maybe Text working fine! :)

Comment: I have a scenario where I have a full size calendar built from a LazyVGrid in the header.. I feel trying to avoid certain views will take me down another rabbit hole.