# Possible to allowsHitTesting on part of view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a button behind a `ScrollView`, but cannot tap it since it's under it. I have a `Spacer` at the top of the scroll view that shows the button. I tried putting `allowsHitTesting(false)` on the `Spacer`, but this is still not letting it pass underneath the `ScrollView`.

This is what the `ScrollView looks like, I cannot tap the "Press" button:

[image]

This is the code, notice the button is in the `ZStack`, and the `Spacer` in the `ScrollView` has the `allowsHitTesting(false)`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button("Press") {
                isPresented = true
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
            .background(Color(.label).ignoresSafeArea())
            ScrollView {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false) // <---- Will not tap thru ScrollView!!
                VStack {
                    Button("Another Press") {
                        isPresented = true
                    }
                    .padding(50)
                    ForEach((0...50), id: \.self) {
                        Text("Some text \($0)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color(.white))
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("Button tapped"))
        }
    }
}
```

Tapping the button in the background under the `Spacer` doesn't work. Is there a way to apply the `allowsHitTesting(false)` to part of the `ScrollView` that the `Spacer` occupies? I obviously don't want to apply `allowsHitTesting(false)` on the entire `ScrollView` because this is a simplistic example but a real app would have tons of interaction views within the `ScrollView`. Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: It is not a Spacer, it is ScrollView itself does not allow tap through.

Comment: That’s my question if it’s possible to apply the allowHitTesting on only part of the scroll view.. the portion that sits behind the space